# Regarding time complexity, big O notation

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

suppose n1,n2 > k.
Does

```
 O(k(n1+n2-k)) = O(k(max(n1,n2)) ?
```

Also, does

```
 O(n1+n2) = O(max(n1,n2)) ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the claim O(k(n1+n2-k)) = O(k(max(n1,n2))  true?

We know that `k < min{n1,n2}` - thus:

```
k(n1+n2-k) = k(max{n1,n2} + min{n1,n2} -k) > k(max{n1,n2})
```

So, it is pretty trivially to show that `O(k(max(n1,n2))` is a subset of `O(k(n1+n2-k))`

We also need to show the other way around, which is also pretty easy because `2k*max{n1,n2}` is in `O(k(max(n1,n2))`, and

```
k(n1+n2-k) < k(max{n1,n2} + max{n1,n2}) -k) < 
           < k(max{n1,n2} + max{n1,n2}))
           = 2 k*max{n1,n2}
```

So, the claim is correct.

> Does O(n1+n2) = O(max(n1,n2)) ?

This is correct. Since `max{n1,n2} <= n1+n2 <= 2*max{n1,n2}`, and we don't care about constants when analyzing big O notation.